# JQuery delay several divs

Tags: jquery, delay, settimeout

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/S5xLM/

With 2 delays and a `setTimeout(function (){ }`

The first delay is working, but the second won't work.

The current object shown is a Gray box. 
The next object (A Blue box) should be shown after the delay.
And finally after another delay, the Green box should be shown.

So instead of (like it is now): Gray -*delay*-> Blue

I want: Gray -*delay*-> Blue -*delay*-> Green.

Thanks.

Comment: Cannot you posted relevant code here?! BTW, you have to...

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/S5xLM/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight **[modification](http://jsfiddle.net/S5xLM/1/)** to your fiddle will get you the desired effect.

```
$('#object1').click(function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#object1').hide();
        $('#object2').show();         
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#object2').hide();
            $('#object3').show();
        }, 1000)
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#object2').hide();
    $('#object3').hide();
    $('#object1').click(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#object1').hide();
            $('#object2').show();
        }, 1000);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#object2').hide();
            $('#object3').show();
        }, 1500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/S5xLM/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#object2').hide();
    $('#object3').hide();
    $('#object1').click(function () {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#object1').hide();
            $('#object2').show();
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#object2').hide();
                $('#object3').show();
            },2000);
        },2000);
    });
});
```